# Jazz scm, update sources

Tags: version-control, jazz, ibm-jazz

How to update sources using jazz scm.

I used this command:

```
lscm load -r "https://rtcserver.com" workspace
```

And it downloaded whole repository into current directory. Unfortunately I don't know how to update sources when there is new code checked-in. I tried to use accept command but it doesn't work for me or I'm doing something wrong:

```
lscm accept -r "https://rtcserver.com" --flow-components -v
```

This one every time returns **"Workspace unchanged."** But it is changed!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the files you wish to change.  Then use "lscm checkin" to create a change set on your repository workspace, and "lscm deliver" if you want to push that change set back to the stream.

See the online help @ http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v2r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fm_cli_usecases.html